# how to get compliance report for SSM for all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, ssm, aws-ssm

How to get compliance report for all the servers in SSM.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/list-compliance-items.html

When i use the Boto3 library but there is only dictionary response for all the servers. This response not able to convert as JSON using json load. End file is invalid json after conversion from AWS dictionary.

Any way to get data in json or csv ?

Comment: What do you mean that's invalid json? Do you have any example and error messages?

Comment: boto3 api response resturns a dictinoary, when i convert that dict into json using json.dumps() its returning a json format file but when i check in json validor it returns invalid json

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: pasted sample script

Comment: @Marcin any updates?

Comment: An example of the incorrect json and how it is obtained?